# Printing char buffer in hex array

Tags: c

I am reading 512 chars into a buffer and would like to display them in hex. I tried the following approach, but it just outputs the same value all the time, despite different values should be received over the network.

```
char buffer[512];
bzero(buffer, 512);
n = read(connection_fd,buffer,511);
if (n < 0) printf("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("Here is the message(%d): %x\n\n", sizeof(buffer), buffer);
```

Is it possible that here I am outputting the address of the buffer array, rather than its content? Is there an easy way in C for this task or do I need to write my own subroutine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing the hexadecimal representation of a char array\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375932/printing-the-hexadecimal-representation-of-a-char-array)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will read the same 512 byte buffer, but convert each *character* to hex on output:

```
char buffer[512];
bzero(buffer, 512);
n = read(connection_fd,buffer,511);
if (n < 0) printf("ERROR reading from socket");

printf("Here is the message:n\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `"%02X"` instead of `"%X"`, since otherwise single-digit values (that is bytes in the range 0-15 decimal) will print as a single digit.

Comment: Great, that works. Thanks guys for all the comments, really helpful to get back into basic C stuff :).

Comment: you want *(unsigned char)*

Answer (score 2):

To display a char in hex you just need the correct format specificer and you need to loop through your buffer:

```
//where n is bytes back from the read:
printf("Here is the message(size %d): ", n);
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
     printf("%x", buffer[i]);
```

The code you were using was printing the address of the buffer which is why it wasn't changing for you.

Since it's been a while for you, if you'd like to see each byte nicely formatted `0xNN` you can also use the `%#x` format:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%#x ", buffer[i]);
```

To get something like:

```
0x10 0x4 0x44 0x52...
```

Comment: It's a shame that `%#x` only prepends `0x` if not 0.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't how C works at all. If anything, you are printing the address of the `buffer` array.

You will need to write a subroutine that loops through each byte in the buffer and prints it to hexadecimal.

And I would recommend you start accepting some answers if you really want people to help you.

Comment: Hmm, never go on SO without that morning cup of coffee.