# How to print buffer to stdout within c++?

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, buffer, stdout

How can I print a buffer in my stdout for debugging purposes? I'm currently a beginner working with OpenGL within XCode (for an iOS app) and have the below lines of code.

```
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

I'd simply like to print to the console the buffer although when trying: `fprintf(stderr, buffer);` I receive an error "No matching function for call to 'fprintf'.

Comment: Iterate over the individual content in `GLubyte`, whatever that is, and print each value, individually.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thanks, just updated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would you mind sharing an example plz?

Comment: Have you written `#include <cstdio>`?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson have just tried with same error.

Comment: Your question is improving, but please show all of your relevant code so we can see what you've done.

Comment: Do you want to output all the contents of buffer to console?

Comment: @Asesh ideally, yes

Answer (score -2):

"fprintf" needs at least 3 argumens (output file, string format, argument) while you provide only 2. C++ compiler tells you that cannot find a matching signature of fprintf with 2 arguments. Besides, there is one more issue to be solved. The buffer probably contains non printable characters so the correct call of fprintf may will not give you the expected result. I would suggest to use a custom buffer printing method maybe something like this [Printing char buffer in hex array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275258/printing-char-buffer-in-hex-array)

Comment: fprintf requires only 2 arguments.