# How to print unsigned char* in NSLog()

Tags: objective-c, c, char, unsigned, nslog

Title pretty much says everything.

would like to print (NOT in decimal), but in unsigned char value (HEX).
example

```
unsigned char data[6] = {70,AF,80,1A, 01,7E};
NSLog(@"?",data); //need this output : 70 AF 80 1A 01 7E
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use printf and a `for` loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357031/how-do-you-convert-buffer-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-c

Comment: I guess you'd have to do `@"%02X %@02X %@02X ...", (unsigned int)data[0], (unsigned int)data[1], ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no format specifier for an `char` array. One option would be to create an `NSData` object from the array and then log the `NSData` object.

```
NSData *dataData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data)];
NSLog(@"data = %@", dataData);
```

Comment: Well, there is a format specifier for a char array -- `s` -- but it expects an null-terminated string and prints as ASCII characters, not hex.

Comment: @HotLicks That's why I didn't mention `%s` because we are not dealing with a null terminated `char` array and the desired output is quite different from what `%s` provides.

Comment: out of topic, but how to just print unsigned char? not an array.

Comment: `%c` is for unsigned char. Pull up the docs for `NSString stringWithFormat:`. Then click the link for "String Format Specifiers". But %c will print the character, not the hex value.

Comment: if want to print hex, use `%x` is it?

Comment: Yes, see what @HotLicks posted in his comment to your question. `%02X` says to print the hex code (X) with a width of two and left padded with zeros as needed.

Comment: Can i store it to `NSString` by using `stringWithFormat:` and get same output ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the standard libraries will do it, so you could write a small hex dump function, or you could use something else that prints non-ambigious full data.   Something like:

```
char buf[1 + 3*dataLength];
strvisx(buf, data, dataLength, VIS_WHITE|VIS_HTTPSTYLE);
NSLog(@"data=%s", buf);
```

For smallish chunks of data you could try to make a NSData and use the debugDescription method.   That is currently a hex dump, but nothing promises it will always be one.

Comment: VIS_WHITE is undeclared. what to include?

Answer (score 1):

To print char* in NSLog try the following:

```
char data[6] = {'H','E','L','L','0','\n'};
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:data];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

You will need to `null` terminate your string.

From Apple Documentation:

```
- (instancetype)initWithUTF8String:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString;
```

Returns an NSString object initialized by copying the characters from a given C array of UTF8-encoded bytes.