# way to convert char array to a hex string and print it in one line

Tags: c

Here is a char array

```
char temp[] ={0x1f,0x2d,0x3c};
```

i want use the __android_log_print to print the temp ,how can convert it to "1f2d3c" and print it in one line without a for loop?

> What  i expected

[image]

> Reality

[image]

Comment: You say that you want to print the characters, but your example is printing the hex value of the characters.

Comment: no,32 or 64    @OldProgrammer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert buffer (byte array) to hex string in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357031/how-do-you-convert-buffer-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-c)

Comment: Note that the word "hex" I added to your title is *crucial* for this question to be interpreted correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute your log function for `printf` in the `printHex` function.  You may be able to get away with not passing the length of the array as long as it is 0 terminated and there are no 0 bytes in the middle of it so you could use `strlen` to find the length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printHex(char* digits, int len)
{
    int i;
    char* str;

    str = malloc(len * 2 + 1);
    memset(str, 0, len * 2 + 1);
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        char temp[3];
        sprintf(temp, "%02x", digits[i]);
        strcat(str, temp);
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
}

int main(void) 
{
    char temp[] ={0x1f,0x2d,0x3c,4,0,5,0,6,7,8};
    printHex(temp, sizeof(temp));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given the example values in his array, I would interpret it as raw binary data, in which 0-values may appears, and `strlen()` would be inappropriate.

Comment: Also, an optimization: You could `sprintf(&str[2*i], ...` directly. This avoids the `strcat` every iteration, which is expensive, as it must scan of the end of the string *every time*. You could also leave out the `memset` then.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is always of size 3, then:

```
__android_log_print(<whatever level>,"%02x%02x%02x", temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]);
```

Comment: any other ways? what if the temp size is 128,that's crazy

Comment: No, what is wrong with a loop then?  You did not specify how big the array was.

Comment: the __android_log_print will add some addtional info and each loop it will create a newline

Comment: so your main problem is `\n` not the `for` loop !

Comment: So loop sprintf and append to a buffer, then print that with %s for the entire string.