# Why to convert byte array to hex string?

Tags: hex, arrays

I have encountered a number of implementations of algorithms for converting a byte array to a hexadecimal string in many languages:

- [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java?s=6|2.4774)
- [How do you convert buffer (byte array) to hex string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357031/how-do-you-convert-buffer-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-c?s=8|2.1466)
- [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array?s=11|1.9262)

Why is this conversion used so often? 
What are the advantages of storing byte arrays as hexadecimal strings?

Comment: How would you store a byte array?

Comment: To examine its contents programatically, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

- To store in a file with a format that doesn't support binary, e.g. CSV.
- To store in a database field that doesn't support binary.
- To send in a protocol that doesn't support binary.
- To embed in other content that doesn't support binary, e.g. XML and JSON.
- To display to a user.
- *Many other reasons...*