# alternative search function and hash vector<struct> C++

Tags: c++

writing program to search address book. fast search time being the biggest priority. professor wants match function to look like

```
Container<const Person*> matches( std::string prefix ) const;
```

i am having trouble defining a function of that sort. Also, a second part was added later on to add a hash function to the program. how would i go about writing hash function for a struct of strings. i have attached important parts of the code.

```
`struct Person 
`{
std::string firstName;
std::string lastName;
std::string email;
`};

`class AddressBook
`{
`public:

AddressBook();
void add(Person person);
void match(std::string namesearch);
std::vector<Person> perV;

`};

void AddressBook::match(std::string namesearch)
`{
for (std::vector<Person>::const_iterator itr = perV.begin(); itr <     `    `   perV.end(); ++itr)
{
    if (strstr(itr->firstName.c_str(), namesearch.c_str()) || 
        strstr(itr->lastName.c_str(), namesearch.c_str()))
    {
        std::cout << itr->firstName << ' ' << itr->lastName
            << std::endl << "Email: " << itr->email << std::endl;
    }

  }

`}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need my match function definition to look like this         
       Container<const Person*> matches( std::string prefix ) const;               i am having trouble defining it                                                           also i need to add a hash function but dont know how to go about that since i have a struct of strings

Answer (score 0):

Writing a hash function for the struct of strings does not sound as a good plan to me. But you can form a tree based on each string attribute you have as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628455/efficient-recent-set-membership-tests-in-c-for-deduplication/49629956#49629956).

I think another good way for search time efficiency is going with [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structures. You can implement it for all string attributes you have and will work well. Time complexity would be O(W*L), where W is number of unique words, and L is the average length of the words.