# How to send 0 value to ESP8266/arduino

Tags: arduino, null, serial-port, esp8266, rs485

I have to send a jpeg by serial from a uart to an esp8266, the jpeg has 0 values in some places, if I send the zeros as is, the received frame contains the chars before the zeros, so what I do is that I send a '0' (0x30 ascii code) instead of a zero,

as you can see on the picture of the merge, on the right the jpeg I receive, on the left the normal jpeg, look at the fifth byte of the top, you will see the difference !

I can't work like that I really want to send char[i]= 0 and receive it

i also give you my code of sending :

```
for (i=0;i<244;i++){
                if (Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i]!=0)
                    sprintf(Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i],"%c", Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i]);
                else
                    Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i] = '0';
                    //sprintf(Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i],"%d", Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i]);
            }
            RS485_Send_CHAN_A("<",1);
            RS485_Send_CHAN_A(Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer,244);
          //  RS485_Send_CHAN_A(">",1);
            RS485_Send_CHAN_A("\0",1);
```

that is the code in the esp to get data :

```
void loop() {
  
   recvWithStartEndMarkers();
   showNewData();
  
   
}


void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static int ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;
   
    
 
    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();
        //delay(5);
  
        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
            
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                compteur++;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars-1) {
                    ndx = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                //Serial.println(ndx,DEC);
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                
                //publish_image();
                newData = true;
            }
        }
        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
            for(int comp;comp<6000;comp++){
              receivedChars[comp] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("This just in ... ");
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        //Serial.println(receivedChars[4],HEX);
        newData = false;
        publish_image();
    }
}
```

[merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEEWf.png)

Comment: I cannot follow you. If you send a 0 you receive a 0. Why on earth would you turn it into 0x30? What do you mean with "contains the chars before the zeros"?

Comment: i d'ont receive 0 if i send  ttt0ppp , i put it in char tab[] ans then when i print(tab) in esp i see just "ttt"

Comment: i have to send ttt0x30ppp to receive ttt0ppp

Answer (score 0):

> i d'ont receive 0 if i send ttt0ppp , i put it in char tab[] ans then
> when i print(tab) in esp i see just "ttt"

You send `0` and you receive `0`. That's not the problem.

The problem is that you cannot print it.

Your idea to send `'0'` is not good because how do you know if your data actually contained a `0x00` or `0x30?` You will see a `'0'` in both cases.

Not every number represents a printable character. See https://www.asciitable.com/

Also C strings are zero terminated. That means if you print a string given by a char pointer, it will print every character until the first `0x00`. That way you don't have to provide a length.

The actual solution to this problem is to print a human-readable form. There are many ways. Just google `char array to hex`

[How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357031/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-c)

And make sure that you send the actual values. Not some string representation.

Comment: thank's a lot for your answer, it's really helpfull, but really i don't care about printing what i want is , send the frame by mqtt receive it by pyhton script and write the picture !

Comment: ok, i change sprintf to : sprintf(Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i],"%02X", Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer[i]); but its still don't work, it print character untill the first 0x00

Comment: this is not how you use sprintf...  sprinft(str, format, ...)  will put the formatted string into buffer str. you cannot do this in-place. also why do you need sprinft in the first place? if you want to send an image through serial, send it's bytes. not some string representation.

Comment: i don't understand how to send it "bytes" the storage_read_Write_buffer" is char type so it's also byte .

Comment: when i send just the storage_buffer it's don't work too , it print until the 0x00

Comment: what I mean is that you do not have to use sprinf to format Storage_ReadWrite_Buffer befor you send it via rs485. if you want to print it on the esp, format it there. you cannot print it as is because a string is terminated with a 0. So whatever comes after the first 0 is ignored. that's why you have to format it it so 0 is printed as '0'  or '0x00', you don't do this on the sending side.

Comment: ok thank you so much, i will try

Comment: i edit my question to add the esp code, what can i apply to "rc" value to format the data

Comment: why do you think I link stuff in my answer? please read it. it shows how to convert a byte array into a printable hex string. run a loop over rc and concatenate a string. Usually it won't make sense to print a whole jpeg file as a hex string though :)

Comment: ok, I give up I'll rather encode my bytes in base64 and send them ! it's easier